# How to format any Dart code fragment as String output

Tags: flutter, dart

I have variable defined in my .dart file like:

```
      Widget code = Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      );
```

How to format this code programatically to get it as String:

```
    """Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
    );"""
```

Comment: do you want to store it as string ?

Comment: No, I need to process the code to String and display, no need to store.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement widget parser that takes string and returns the widgets composition
Or you can use  [dynamic_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_widget) to achieve your use case.